# Using other user leads on my report chart

Tags: leads, dashboard, charts, report-chart

We had only 1 user, so I add another user with administrator permission (like myself), I did some changes on my dashboard and I want the same exact dashboard shows in the other user too.

I couldn't find a way, so I start manually, but it's not possible.
For example, when I add the "Report chart" component, it can't find any leads, however, we have thousands of leads and this user can see leads on the report page using Filter

[image]

So my question is how can I manage this in the page dashboard? it doesn't have any "Filter by Owner".

Comment: First, Please check whether you have able to view the leads in any report, then you can able to add that report into your dashboard component

Comment: Yes, I can, but I don't know how it is possible, normally I would go to the Report Chart and select it via there, but in the way you propose I have no idea @MohanRaj

Comment: I am saying, Please create a new Lead report, then you can know how many number of leads you can able to access in your org. Then you can use that report in dashboard's report component.

Comment: Thank you a lot @MohanRaj , I didn't know we have a Report section, it was hidden by default, and I found out how to edit all the built-in report marketing charts, so I've solved my problem, have a nice evening!

Comment: Please drop that as answer and accept it. Otherwise this question continue as open for answers. And happy to help you in this case. Have a great weekend!!